# ternary and assignment operator precedence

Tags: c++

On MSVC v9.0, if I do this:

```
int myvalue;
myvalue = true ? 1 : 0;
```

then it seems that `?:` is evaluated before '='. Is this a guarantee? I am using this table as a reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

However, both operators are in the same row, so I'm not sure if they are evaluated in the order I expect or if this is guaranteed by the standard. Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link:

> Operators that are in the same cell (there may be several rows of operators listed in a cell) are evaluated with the same precedence, in the given direction. For example, the expression a=b=c is parsed as a=(b=c), and not as (a=b)=c because of right-to-left associativity.

Since both `=` and `?:` are in the same cell and have right-to-left associativity, the ternary is guaranteed to evaluate first.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed to know. I've usually visited that page only to pay attention to the table itself, I never realized there was more to read below it! My mistake entirely!

Answer (score 7):

In this statement

```
int myvalue = true ? 1 : 0;
```

there's only one operator, the ternary operator. There's no assignment operator here, so precedence doesn't matter.

Don't confuse initialization with assignment:

```
int myvalue;
myvalue = true ? 1 : 0; // now priorities are important
```

Comment: my example is wrong, my mistake. I am actually asking about your modified version

Comment: Then see @Mark Ransom's answer

Comment: don't confuse declarations and statements: `int myvalue = true ? 1 : 0;` is a declaration.

Comment: @ouah declaration statement is a type of statement syntactically, just like expression statements and compound statements for instance

Comment: @Kos in C a declaration is not a statement, see `6.8` in C99 to see what is a statement.

Comment: @ouah It's actually a definition, not a declaration, `extern int myvalue;` would be a declaration.

Comment: @ouah In C++ it definitely is, see `6.7` in C++11

Comment: @RobertDailey a definition is a kind of declaration

Comment: @ouah A declaration is *part of* a definition, if you want to think of it that way, but a definition is not a declaration.

Comment: @RobertDailey C99, 6.7p5 *"A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that [...]:"*

Comment: @Kos apparently C and C++ use different terminology. In C a declaration is not a statement but in C++ a declaration is a statement.

Comment: @ouah I think we're saying the same thing. A declaration is a subset of a definition.

Comment: @ouah probably a legacy thing from the old C times when declarations had to go before everything else?

Comment: @RobertDailey that would imply that there are definitions which aren't declarations

Comment: @Kos No it doesn't imply that. It means it's impossible to have a definition without a declaration. But a declaration ISN'T a definition, thus a definition is NOT a declaration (it includes a declaration, but has more to it than that). It would be more correct IMHO to say a definition contains a declaration, than to call a definition a declaration directly.

Comment: @RobertDailey Haha, now we're into the infamous valley of semantics of "is-a". Fact: Every definition *exhibits all the properties of a declaration*. Define the "set of declarations" `Decl` and "set of definitions" `Def` through exhibiting these properties, and you'll clearly have that `Def ⊂ Decl`. Or alternatively `anyDefinition instanceof IDeclaration` if that rings a bell more.

Comment: "A declaration is a subset of a definition" sounds a bit off, but if you'd said "is a part of", then I'd agree.

Comment: A subset is naturally a part of its superset, so the "is a part of" is implied :)

Answer (score 0):

They are evaluated right to left, as it written in the table you linked. It is equivalent of this:

```
int myvalue = (true ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-to-left:

```
int myValue1 = 20, myValue2 = 30;

myValue1 = true ? 1 : 0; // which is the same as:
myValue1 = ((true) ? (1) : (0));

// myValue == 1 && myValue2 == 30

true ? myValue1 : myValue2 = 5; // which is the same as:
(true) ? (myValue1) : ((myValue2) = (5));

// myValue == 1 && myValue2 == 30

false ? myValue1 : myValue2 = 5; // which is the same as:
(false) ? (myValue1) : ((myValue2) = (5));

// myValue == 1 && myValue2 == 5
```

This is guaranteed in the C++ language